# How read values of config/filesystems.php

Tags: laravel-5, configuration, filesystems

How in laravel 5.8 read values of config/filesystems.php, with default value :

```
return [

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),


    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),


    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I expected as :

```
$filesystem_pablic_path  = config('filesystem.disks.public');
```

but empty value returned ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try plural. `$filesystem_pablic_path  = config('filesystems.disks.public');`